# Filter Azure blob search using blob name

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I have a storage account containing blobs named to produce a virtual hierarchy:

```
Data/2016/image01.jpg
   w=640
   h=480
Data/2017/image02.jpg
   w=320
   h=240
...
```

All blobs hold metadata fields containing image width(w) and height(h)

I've implemented a Search service and added the blob metadata as searchable fields.

This works fine to search over all blobs and filter by w or h:

```
search=*&$filter=(w eq 640)
```

I'm also confused with blob names.  AFAIK after Containers, all blobs are stored flat and the virtual hierarchy (as seen in the Azure portal when browsing blobs) is just derived from adding '/' in the blob name.  However when you fetch the `metadata_storage_name` it only returns the last segment of the name not the full path.

How can I further filter by blob name?  For example only return blobs that contain '2017' in their name and w==640

**Edit:**  I partially solved my problem.  Turns out I was adding `$queryType=full` not `queryType=full` to my search.  So something like this will work: queryType=full&search=image02*&$filter=(w eq 640) but still no way to include the blob "path" in the search.

Answer (score 0):

There is also **metadata_storage_path** field which contains full path. Unfortunately it contains also entire blob storage URL.

**metadata_storage_path** (Edm.String) - the full URI of the blob, including the storage account. For example, https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/my-container/my-folder/subfolder/resume.pdf

Comment: Thanks! But then I'd need to add metadata_storage_path as a searchable field and since it's also base64 encoded and includes the entire URL I can't imagine it would be very efficient.

Comment: Well it wouldn't be that bad, it's just comparing against index, only index would be larger than others. It boils down to how many blobs are you expecting. I guess the only other way would be to add the path as metdadata yourself, which is very unfortunate to say the least.